# How do I fix problems with opening views

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

im having a problem where my function to open a second view controller isn't working and is just crashing.
here is the code that crashes it:

```
        let NewRecipe = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewRecipeVC")as! NewRecipe
        present(NewRecipe,animated: true)
```

it is giving me an error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1859c41a8)
```

All I'm trying to do is open the view controller called "NewRecipeVC"

Comment: Did you set the Storyboard ID for that VC?

Answer (score 0):

The message "EXC_BREAKPOINT" sounds like you have a breakpoint set in your code, not like you have an error.

Note that you should avoid force-casting using `!`. That will crash if your view controller is not the expected type. Use `if let` or `guard let` instead.

Comment: now it is spitting this: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`   and here is the code now `if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewRecipeVC") present(vc,animated: true)`